# The quad tag is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just spent some time removing the [quad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quad) from many questions because it was used incorrectly. The problem is that in natural language it has many different uses:

- quad as in quadrature (numerical integration)
- quad as opposed to a triangle (in drawing software)
- quadruple precision
- ...

On Stack Overflow, it's supposed to mean the [`scipy.integrate.quad` subpackage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html).

I'd suggest to rename the tag to `scipy-quad`.

Comment: Have you reviewed/cleaned up all the questions in the tag prior to posting this request, or is a cleanup still needed?  <200 questions isn't bad at least if it still needs done.

Comment: I've ploughed through it now. About 75 left.

Comment: @DanNeely Is there anything I can do to help out?

Comment: Probably not, anything else would require a moderator to have noticed the question